# extend class with private constructor in other package

Tags: java, android, recognizer-intent

I want to overwrite a view of RecognizerIntent in android. To do this, I try to extend the RecognizerIntent class in Android as follows:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

public class RecInt extends RecognizerIntent {

    public RecInt(Context c) {
        super(c);
//if I don't call super here, there is an error 'There is no default constructor available in RecognizerIntent'
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recint);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error

> RecognizerIntent() is not public in android.speech.RecognizerIntent,
>   Cannot be accessed from outside package.

Is there any way I can still extend a non-public class?

I want to do this so that when `RecInt` is started

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
startActivityForResult(intent,100);
```

the view in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_recint)` shows up, instead of the `RecognizerIntent` view.

Comment: Umm.  `public class RecognizerIntent 
extends Object`...

Comment: Change the package of `RecInt` to `android.speech`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but `RecognizerIntent` is neither a `View` nor an `Activity`.

Comment: And is `public` co shoould be extendable without any problems...

Comment: The class is public, but there is no constructor. Any ideas if it is still possible?

Comment: Given this question and [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412961/modify-activity-layout-programmatically), it seems that you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of Android's components and classes. You cannot do what you're attempting to do. An `Intent` is basically a description of an action and its details. It has no inherent `View` or `Activity` for you to modify.

Comment: ok, will work on my understanding. so there is just no way to change the content view of the activity that is started using RecognizerIntent.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH?

Comment: There is no Activity started for that Intent. It pops open a dialog for you to talk to, right?

Comment: yes its a dialog. so its actually a fragment living in the activity that starts the RecognizerIntent.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

Comment: Its a Dialog, I believe, not a Fragment.

Comment: actually the documentation in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7360591/core/java/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.java says 'Starts an activity that will prompt the user for speech and send it through a speech recognizer.'

Answer (score 1):

> RecognizerIntent() is not public

The *constructor* is not public. [The class is public](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html)

You can extend the class but you cant call `super` . It is unclear why you are doing so, or giving a Context. It does not appear to provide that constructor

Plus, that class is not an Activity , so all that onCreate code is just wrong

Comment: I wrote super because otherwise I am seeing the error 'There is no default constructor available in RecognizerIntent'. Any other ideas how I could still extend the view in RecognizerIntent? I added some more context why I want to change the view

Comment: This isn't quite right. You cannot extend a class that has only private constructors.

Comment: @MikeM. How do you mean?

Comment: In order to extend a class with at least one defined constructor, your subclass has to call one of those constructors from its constructor, but if the super constructors are private, not even subclasses can access them. If you try to extend `RecognizerIntent`, e.g., your IDE should pitch a fit, no matter how you try to implement or omit a constructor.

Comment: Got it. So, overall, this attempt at a subclass is incorrect for the end goal

Comment: Yeah, especially for this particular class. `RecognizerIntent` is just a bunch of static constants, and a helper method. They defined a private constructor to specifically disable doing anything with the class, other than using its static members.

Comment: I was just thinking that I kinda misspoke in my earlier comments. I shoulda said "You cannot extend a class _in another file/package_ that has only private constructors." It's not strictly the private constructor that prevents subclassing there. It's that any subclass you would try to make would not have access to that constructor. That is, if you could, e.g., make an inner class in `RecognizerIntent`, you could extend it. But you can't do that, obviously. Just a nitpicky detail. Carry on. :-)